How to swap values between two columns based on conditions in Python
I am trying to switch values between the Range and Unit columns in the dataframe below based on the condition that if Unit contains -, then replace Unit with Range and Range with Unit. To do that, I am creating a unit_backup column so that I don't lose the original Unit value.
1. dataframe
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'Range':['34-67',12,'gm','45-90'],
              'Unit':['ml','35-50','10-100','mg']})
sample_df

    Range       Unit
0   34-67         ml
1   12         35-50
2   gm        10-100
3   45-90         mg

2. Function
Below is the code I have tried but I am getting an error in this:
def range_unit_correction_fn(df):

    # creating backup of Unit column
    df['unit_backup'] = df['Unit']
    
    # condition check
    if df['unit_backup'].str.contains("-"):
        
        # if condition is True then replace `Unit` value with `Range` and `Range` with `unit_backup`
        df['Unit'] = df['Range']
        df['Range'] = df['unit_backup']
        
    else:
        # if condition False then keep the same value
        df['Range'] = df['Range']
    
    # drop the backup column
    df = df.drop(['unit_backup'],axis=1)
    
    return df


Applying the above function on the dataframe

sample_df = sample_df.apply(range_unit_correction_fn, axis=1)
sample_df

Error:
   1061 def apply_standard(self):
   1062     if self.engine == "python":
-> 1063         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
...
----> 4     if df['unit_backup'].str.contains("-"):
      5         df['Unit'] = df['Range']
      6         df['Range'] = df['unit_backup']

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

It seems like some silly mistake, but I am not sure where I am going wrong.
Appreciate any sort of help here.

Use pd.where() to restrict operations to particular rows.

@Barmar I am aware of np.where() but not pd.where(). But still tried and got this error: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'where' Not using np.where as I dont want to use another library.

SOrry, that was a typo, I meant np.where(), which can be used with pandas df.

@Barmar .. sure no problem :)

When you access df['unit_backup'], you get a scalar string value, not a pandas Series, so calling .str on it raises an error.
To fix it you can check the condition directly on the string value in a row-wise approach:
def range_unit_correction_fn(df):
    # creating backup of Unit column
    df['unit_backup'] = df['Unit']

    # condition check
    if '-' in df['unit_backup']:
        # if condition is True then replace `Unit` value with `Range` and `Range` with `unit_backup`
        df['Unit'] = df['Range']
        df['Range'] = df['unit_backup']

    # drop the backup column
    df = df.drop(['unit_backup'])

    return df


After reading your answer text I realized my mistake. Thanks alot. Really Appreciate your help.

Alternatively, in one line, with no need for a temporary column or column 'backup':
sample_df[['Range', 'Unit']] = sample_df[['Unit', 'Range']].where(sample_df['Unit'].str.contains('-'), sample_df[['Range', 'Unit']].values)

which gives:
    Range Unit
0   34-67   ml
1   35-50   12
2  10-100   gm
3   45-90   mg


Wow .. this is really impressive. I had no idea it could be done like this. Thanks for showing this alternative way. Appreciate your help !!!
